# Datagrid, don't show details when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a standard datagrid defined < Datagrid...> 
In this datagrid I also have the standard "rowdetails", so when a row in the datagrid is clicked, the detail is shown. Everything works as expected.

But, I in each row in the datagrid I have a < button ..> in place and the problem is, that when the button is clicked, I don't want the detail of the row to show. If the row is clicked anywhere else the detail should be correctly shown, but when the button is pressed it should only do the button stuff, but not show the detail of the row.

How can this be achieved?

So far, I tried to attach a PreviewMouseDown event to the button and then in code behind:

```
    private void OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button) sender;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

This correctly prevents the datagrid row detail from showing, when the button is clicked, but it also prevents the button itself from performing its attached Click event method.

Comment: Moving the code of your Click event handler to your PreviewMouseDown event handler may be a solution, not the best one I admit.

Comment: Oh damn, I can't believe I haven't thought of that. Post it as an answer and if no "proper" solution is posted I will do just that and trigger my click even function manually from the previewmousedown event handling function.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess here:

Could you perhaps make the row clicked event raise after the mouse button has been clicked. For example, MouseClickUp instead of OnMouseClick. And the have the button even raise by OnMouseClick. Maybe then the button handler is called first and dismisses the row event?

Maybe instead of using the button you could use a CellClick event perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to check what `UIElement` the user actually clicked on in your `OnPreviewMouseDown` handler:

```
private void OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    IInputElement element = e.MouseDevice.DirectlyOver;
    if (element != null && element is FrameworkElement)
    {
        Button button = GetParentOfType<Button>(element as FrameworkElement);
        if (button != null)
        {
            // The Button was clicked
        }
        else e.Handled = true;
    }
    else e.Handled = true;
}
```

The `GetParentOfType` method is a simple recursive function that checks the type of the parent of each successive `UIElement` and returns the expected type if found:

```
public T GetParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject element) where T : DependencyObject
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (element == null) return null;
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
    if (parent == null && ((FrameworkElement)element).Parent is DependencyObject)
        parent = ((FrameworkElement)element).Parent;
    if (parent == null) return null;
    else if (parent.GetType() == type || parent.GetType().IsSubclassOf(type)) 
        return parent as T;
    return GetParentOfType<T>(parent);
}
```